# Dictionary with nested levels rearranged to 1 level

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary with 3 levels:

```
f = {1:{-1:{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 0:{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 1:{'a': 5, 'b': 6}},
2:{-2:{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, -1:{'a': 9, 'b': 10}, 0:{'a': 11, 'b': 12}, 1:{'a': 13, 'b': 14}, 2:{'a': 15, 'b': 16}}}
```

The actual values of the dictionary are always at the lowest, 3rd level, everything before that is keys. I am looking for a way to flatten the dictionary into a single-level dictionary, but still keep the three separate labels: `m` from `1` to `N`, `n` from `-m` to `m`, and `p = 'a', 'b'`.

I thought about doing it with a string, e.g.

```
f = {"1,-1,a": 1, "1,-1,a": 2, "1,0,a": 3, ...}
```

but things break down further in the code when `m` and `n` become double-digit numbers. So ideally I am looking for something like:

```
f[[m][n][p]] = value
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension should work:

```
f = {1:{-1:{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 0:{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 1:{'a': 5, 'b': 6}},
2:{-2:{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, -1:{'a': 9, 'b': 10}, 0:{'a': 11, 'b': 12}, 1:{'a': 13, 'b': 14}, 2:{'a': 15, 'b': 16}}}

d = { (a,b,c):v for a,da in f.items() for b,db in da.items() for c,v in db.items()}
```

result:

```
for k,v in d.items(): print(k,":",v)

(1, -1, 'a') : 1
(1, -1, 'b') : 2
(1, 0, 'a') : 3
(1, 0, 'b') : 4
(1, 1, 'a') : 5
(1, 1, 'b') : 6
(2, -2, 'a') : 7
(2, -2, 'b') : 8
(2, -1, 'a') : 9
(2, -1, 'b') : 10
(2, 0, 'a') : 11
(2, 0, 'b') : 12
(2, 1, 'a') : 13
(2, 1, 'b') : 14
(2, 2, 'a') : 15
(2, 2, 'b') : 16

d[2,-1,'b'] # --> 10
```